The denominator of $\frac{L(E,1)}{\Omega_E}$ dividing the conductor of $E$

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with conductor $N$, real period $\Omega_E$ and L-function $L$. Then the denominator of
$$\frac{L(E, 1)}{\Omega_E}\in\mathbb{Q}$$
divides $N$.

Where can I find this theorem (and what number does that theorem have in a given reference)? Or, if the exact theorem cannot be found in a reference, can you at least tell me what available theorems (with references) is it implied by?
Context:
I asked AI about the denominator of
$$\frac{L(E,1)}{\Omega_E}\in\mathbb{Q}$$
and it answered by the above theorem, but it failed to locate the theorem in a given reference. I will appreciate any help.

For analytic rank $>0$, it’s trivial since $L(E,1)$ vanishes. For analytic rank $0$, see theorem 3.1 here. The main non-trivial part of the proof is in proving Manin-Drinfeld.

@Kstar I'm very new in this area and I'm particularly interested in the analytic rank $0$; could you please explain why the theorem involving the Neron differential gives the divisibility theorem in question?

The period $\Omega_E$ is given as the integral of the Néron differential over $E(\mathbb{R})$ so the constant $M$ being rational is exactly the statement you are asking about- showing the index $[E(\mathbb{R}):E_0(\mathbb{R})]$ multiplied by the Manin constant divides the conductor is a little more non-trivial.

@KStar If I understand correctly, it proves that $\frac{L(E,1)}{\Omega_E}\in\mathbb{Q}$, but why does the denominator divide the conductor of $E$?

Indeed it doesn’t show that the denominator divides the conductor of $E$- currently trying to find about this. I was answering your question of what the denominator of the rational constant is.

@KStar You said that "showing it is a little more non-trivial". By that you mean that it has been proved or hasn't?

To be honest, I haven’t seen that result before that the denominator divides the conductor $N$, but I can believe it’s true so I’m trying to find a reference for this.

Yeah I suddenly realised this is false since $|E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{tors}}|$ is bounded by 16, so just choose some prime conductor $N$ larger than this.

Off-topic:  Really wish you hadn't deleted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4999363/modular-equations-for-webers-mathfrakf-algorithm?noredirect=1 -- now there's nowhere to post the results of my chat with Dr. Sutherland.

Unfortunately, this is false. As noted in the comments, this is trivial if $L(E,1)=0$, so we may assume this value is nonzero, so we are in analytic rank $0$ case. BSD formula predicts that
$$\frac{L(E,1)}{\Omega_E}=\frac{|\mathrm{Sha}_E|\prod_p c_p}{|E(\mathbb Q)_{\mathrm{tors}}|^2}.$$
If you don't know what the terms in the numerator are, no worries, since we are mainly focused on the denominator. It may not be the "pure" denominator in case of cancellations, but this already indicates this will be false, because the quantity there, $|E(\mathbb Q)_{\mathrm{tors}}|^2$, has very little relation to the conductor.
You can find specific counterexamples with help of LMFDB. The first curve with nontrivial torsion is this curve of conductor $11$, and you can see that the BSD quotient is $\frac{1}{5}$ with denominator $5$ (there is partial, but not full, cancellation), which does not divide $11$.
Unfortunately, even the best AI available today is not reliable when it comes to mathematical results.

@japjap As indicated in my answer, the denominator you are after always divides the order of torsion squared. Mazur's torsion theorem tells us exactly what the possible orders are.
